# Proving CPA security using a PRG in place of a PRF

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

I am stuck on a question involving a security proof. Any Hints on how to approach this is helpful and greatly appreciated.

Question is:

> State whether the following scheme has indistinguishable
>   encryptions in the presence of an eavesdropper and whether it is CPA-secure: In this case, the key is random $k\in \{0,1\}^n$.
>
> To encrypt $m\in \{0,1\}^{n+1}$, pick a random $r\in \{0,1\}^n$, and send $\langle r, G(r)\oplus m\rangle$, where $G$ is a PRG with expansion factor $n+1$.

I think it is CPA- secure, but am having a hard time proving it. My rough idea is, given a PPT adversary A, construct an algorithm D, takes input $w\in \{0,1\}^{n+1}$, with no oracles. But how would D answer queries? Its not like the case where a PRF is used in place of $G$, when D can use its oracle to distinguish a random function from a pseudorandom function.

Comment: Hint: tell me where the encryption/ decryption algorithms use the secret key.

Comment: It does not use the key at all. How does that help at all though?

Comment: The key is what allows a legitimate recipient to decrypt but not an eavesdropper.

Comment: It's clearly not. given $C = (r',C')$ you can compute $m=C' \xor G(r')$. Notice that $G$ is public and known by everyone.

Comment: Oh Yes if $G$ was known publicly then this question is easy, but that was one of the things I was not sure about.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help. They really make a difference.